# Почему dockerd запрашивает root-права, когда они уже имеются?

Tags: ubuntu, docker

Сразу говорю - я не до конца знаю, для чего нужен докер и как его правильно использовать. Просто эта чтука нужна для Outline - хочу поднять свой VPN сервер.
Такс, есть удаленная машина на ubuntu, на нее надо поставить докер и запустить его, с чем у меня собсна проблемы.
При запуске по-человечески ошибок не выдает, однако запущенным он не становится:

```
root@goorm:/home/sergey# service docker start
 * Starting Docker: docker                                               [ OK ]
root@goorm:/home/sergey# service docker status
 * Docker is not running
```

Пытаюсь привести его в дествие командой dockerd:

```
failed to start daemon: Error initializing network
controller: error obtaining controller instance: 
failed to create NAT chain DOCKER: iptables failed: 
iptables -t nat -N DOCKER: iptables v1.6.0: can't 
initialize iptables table `nat': 
Permission denied (you must be root)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
 (exit status 3)
```

На всяк случ вот полный вывод от dockerd:

[dockerd.txt](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/967650694553284648/1092161650964045956/dockerd.txt)

Что скажете, господа?

Comment: `sudo service docker start`. `dockerd` ругается на то, что ему не хватает прав создать виртуальный интерфейс и настроить правила обработки трафика

Comment: @PakUula скажите, а что делать то с этим? он и так из под рута запущен, куда ещё прав-то?

Comment: Пардон, я был не прав. На что ругается `dockerd`: нет нескольких приложений. `sudo apt install fuse-overlayfs`, `sudo apt install kmod_29` (или `kmod_30` - в зависимости от версии системы). Но про рута я таки не понял - вам же в конце чётко написали: *can't initialize iptables table `nat': Permission denied (**you must be root**)* . Про рута вы нам какую-то неправду сказали

Comment: @PakUula вы почитайте dockerd.txt (а точнее его первую строку), там видно что команда запущена из-под рута (root@goorm:/home/sergey # dockerd) обратите внимание на решётку и root@...

Comment: @PakUula `root@goorm:~# apt install fuse-overlayfs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package fuse-overlayfs
root@goorm:~# apt install kmod_29
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package kmod_29
root@goorm:~# apt install kmod_30
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package kmod_30`

Comment: @PakUula помогите же мне, пожалуйста

Comment: @PakUula я вот еще что обнаружил (с тем же баганным рутом): `root@goorm:~# sudo umount /
umount: /: must be superuser to unmount`

Comment: Вам нужно разобраться с рутом и его правами. Что-то у вас не так с этим пользователем. Что пишет команда `id`?

Comment: @PakUula `uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)`

Comment: @pakuula извиняюсь за такую задержку(